# Java Collection Implementation for TextBoxes

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a C# implementation of using Collections to store text boxes in a sort of List structure and the object can have its own methods, which is useful for me.

```
class PieceNameBoxArray : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
   private readonly Form myForm;

   public PieceNameBoxArray(Form host)
   {
      myForm = host;
      this.AddNewTextBox();
   }

   public TextBox this[int Index]
   {
      get
      {
         return (TextBox)this.List[Index];
      }
   }

   public TextBox AddNewTextBox()
   {
      //adds a new next box
   }
}
```

This is my implementation in C#, and then in my main form class I can call...

```
PieceNameBoxArray textBoxArray = new PieceNameBoxArray(this);
```

How might I go about implementing this in Java?  Essentially I just want a List Collection of text boxes that I will be able to dynamically add to my form.

EDIT: I am using Swing as my GUI Java library in my project.  Makes it look similar to Visual Studio's C# Windows Forms.

Comment: Post your attempt and we'll help.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've put in any effort (in either language)...

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend, especially for a beginner, to browse through the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Specifically, the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) by Josh Bloch, and in particular its [introduction to the List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and the [lesson on Custom Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/custom-implementations/index.html). This will tell you **why** you may want to write your own implementation, and how to get started.

<sup>(Whether that's a good design is an entirely different question.)</sup>